# Migrating from django celery tasks to apache airflow

Tags: django, celery, airflow, celery-task

I have a python/django project (running in docker containers). There's a data collection workflow which is implemented via celery tasks, which depend on each other and run in parallel.

I want to migrate all this logic to apache airflow, because I assume it suits for my needs and it will be more convenient to start and restart the tasks, build more complex workflow, monitor and debug.

I've never used airflow before. Is my plan sane? Where do I start? What executors should I use?

Comment: I would say that your plan makes no sense. Airflow is not execution an engine. Running an arbitrary task at any point of time is not a common pattern in Airflow - it typically schedules DAGs so that some execution system runs them at appointed time (Cerlery or Kubernetes). If you for whatever reason dislike Celery, then make Django run stuff on Kubernetes directly. I know people who use [Huey](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to achieve the same. Me personally - I would always use Celery first until I come to something it cannot do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense, there is the same celery executor on apache airflow as well.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/executor/index.html

You can replicate your code to test on the below airflow docker.

https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

On the airflow tool you can manage, schedule, monitor all these code by tasks on the dag

There are dags examples on

https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/example_dags

You can start with this one -

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try